# Android Studio on Windows does not have JDK path

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android Studio on Windows (latest version, Hedgehog) does not have a JDK path! Very frustrating, as I can't find it in settings nor in the project structure, as 99% of all related questions seem to have that answer. Any chance someone knows why this and/or how I can change the JDK? I am assuming the SDK is not meant for the Java path, right? So that's why you see the Android API.

[image]

[image]

I want to test out changing my Java version, because I am constantly getting this error when I try to add a plugin to my app. Desperately hoping that it will fix it when a newer Java version is being used.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Settings > Build,Exe.. > Build Gradle > Gradle

Comment: Sadly, that also does not show anything for me. Please see the screenshot in my post (I edited it).

Comment: try searching "jdk" in search bar or reinstalling jdk

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this. I don't know why no documentation or answer says this, but you can access the gradle and JDK configuration via

```
File > New Projects Setup > Default Project Structure > gradle (tab)
```

[image]

Sharing this as I hope it will be useful for others as well.